# FBRequest requestForMe startWithCompletionHandler method not working on device

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios6, simulator

I have followed all the directions from the Facebook Developer website about integrating Facebook SDK 3.1 into iOS 6. My code runs perfectly on the iPhone 6.0 Simulator (user can log into Facebook), but when I run the app on my iPhone, the function [FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler] doesn't generate a response. According to the Facebook Developer website, it should either be successful or return an error, but it does neither. The app just sits there waiting for a response that never comes. My code is below:

```
- (void)populateUserDetails {
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"logged in");
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
             }
         }];
    } else {
       NSLog(@"no active session");
    }
}
```

Using breakpoints, I determined that the activeSession is always open, so the startWithCompletionHandler: method is actually called. Maybe it's a build problem since it runs fine on the Simulator? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered my own question: go to your Facebook app page and make sure that a "0" value hasn't been inserted automatically for your App Store ID. I had already set my bundle ID to the correct value (which you also have to do), but overnight, Facebook automatically set the App Store ID value to 0. Everything worked as soon as I removed that value.

Comment: this did not work for me. i also set up a test app at the Facebook portal and provided a new app id (store id set to 0), and still nothing.

Answer (score 5):

> make sure that a "0" value hasn't been inserted automatically for your App Store
>   ID

App Store ID is different than Bundle ID. Like it says on Facebook: "For security reasons, we check the bundle ID before authorizing your app". So you should set that exactly as the same as it is in Xcode which you did.

But App Store ID ("iPhone App Store ID that we can link to on Facebook") you set them when you already submitted you app and it's accepted. Therefore, for developing purpose you should set iPhone and iPad(if any) to 0 which I did and it's working fine on both Simulator and iPhone iOS 6.0.

It wasn't because of that 0, maybe you fixed something else?

Comment: this did not work for me. i also set up a test app at the Facebook portal and provided a new app id (store id set to 0), and still nothing.

Comment: @robdashnash Hi, lots of things could have happened to your app and those stages you should've done to integrate your app with Facebook SDK. Follow the basic tutorial for iOS and when it get to FB app dashboard this is how it works, believe me I have apps in both dev and production using the same thing. If you still have a problem, ask a question with snippet of your code.