# User location return null value

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios6

In my application while i retrive  the user location its return a Null value, and birthdate also returns also Null value, Code as follows,

```
 - (void)populateUserDetails {
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error)           {
         if (!error) {
             self.userNameLabel.text = user.name;
             self.userProfileImage.profileID = [user objectForKey:@"id"];
             self.userbirthday.text=user.birthday;
             self.userloc=[[user objectForKey:@"location"]  objectForKey:@"name"];

         }
     }];
   }
 }
```

What is rong with code?Please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: have you check with this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611847/fbrequest-requestforme-startwithcompletionhandler-method-not-working-on-device)

Comment: yeah... Not only user name is visible properly only the problem with the location and birthdate

Comment: the doc here [Facebook Doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/user-data-ios-sdk/). mention that u need permission for birthday and location for u to be able to retrieve them.

Comment: have you tried self.userloc = [user.location objectForKey:@"name"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For birthday and location you need to be granted with such permission. So you need to request the permission like so: [Facebook SDK Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/user-data-ios-sdk/#step2)

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_location", // you need to have this permission
                            @"user_birthday", // to be approved
                            @"user_likes",
                            nil];
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];
                                     }];
}
```

And then use the FBRequest to retrieve the birthday and location. You can access username as it does not require special permission to do so.